# Accidentally moving windows using mouse

Tags: macos, windows, ui

I'm ex-Windows user. There was no way to drag maximized window, but it's possible in OS X (I have Mavericks).

There is full screen mode, but I have found one annoying thing there - it's too hard to get access to the Dock. I have to point my cursor at the bottom of the screen and wait for a long time, unlike default behavior in non-fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to lock maximized windows, allowing to move them only with <kbd>⌘</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Currently, no, this isn't possible.**

There's no such thing as maximising a window in OS X — I therefore presume you are referring to a window which has been stretched to fill the entire screen (as much as possible — i.e. not behind the menu bar). Since there is no difference between a window which has been enlarged and a 'maximised' window, there's no problem in dragging the window away from the menu bar, and it's not possible to prevent.

If you're always moving your windows, try something like [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net). This lets you maximise any window by dragging it to the top of the screen.